# replacing a pattern using sed command

Tags: shell, sed

I want to replace a pattern by using sed command. I have a file with below data.

```
50%%R39%35%R43%-35%R4Z%10%RRN%1110%R0M%-950
```

Now I need to replace the pattern `%RRN%<something>%` with `%RRN%0%`. output should be like this.

```
50%%R39%35%R43%-35%R4Z%10%RRN%0%R0M%-950
```

For this I have used below command

```
sed 's/%RRN%\(.*\)%/%RRN%0%/g'
```

But I didn't get the correct output. It is coming as below.

```
50%R39%35%R43%-35%R4Z%10%RRN%0%-950
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution would be use `[^%]\+` in place of `.*`

```
sed 's/%RRN%\([^%]\+\)%/%RRN%0%/g'
```

Output:

```
50%%R39%35%R43%-35%R4Z%10%RRN%0%R0M%-950
```

Comment: Sorry Jkshah, I have edited the question...Output should be like below `50%%R39%35%R43%-35%R4Z%10%RRN%0%R0M%-950`

Comment: I want the new pattern with `%RRN%0%` whereas, in your output it is coming as same `%RRN%1110%`

Comment: @vishal Did you check with my edited regex? I have updated regex as well as output

Comment: @jkshah It was the `+` in your regex that made problems in first post, using `*` should do it: `sed 's/%RRN%[^%]*%/%RRN%0%/g'`

Comment: @Jotne agree an I needed to escape that. now whether to use `+` or `*` is requirement dependent

Answer (score 0):

If you like to try with `awk`, you can do:

```
echo '50%%R39%35%R43%-35%R4Z%10%RRN%1110%R0M%-950' | awk '{sub(/%RRN%[^%]*%/,"%RRN%0%")}1'
50%%R39%35%R43%-35%R4Z%10%RRN%0%R0M%-950
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe '$a="0%";s/(%RRN%)[^%]*%/$1$a/g'
```